# XCTest press and drag doesn't work when there's text underneath

Tags: swift, swiftui, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am trying to write a UI Test in Xcode for dragging a dot around the screen. The test had been working for weeks, but as soon as I put text behind the starting position of the dot, the UI Test is no longer able to drag the dot around (even though it's totally draggable in the actual app!). I’m using SwiftUI to develop the app. Why is this happening?

Code:

```
func testShouldDragDot() throws {
    let endLocation = app.otherElements["endLocation"]
    let thankYouText = app.staticTexts["thankYouText"]
    let dot = app.otherElements["dot"]
    
    dot.press(forDuration: 1, thenDragTo: endLocation)

    XCTAssertEqual(thankYouText.label, "Thank You")
}
```

Without text behind dot, it works fine:

[image]

But with text behind dot, the test fails:

[image]

Comment: Your code base is SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: Thanks for asking—updated my post to say I used SwiftUI to develop the app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and manually change the `.zIndex` of each element to make sure they are correct in the hierarchy.

Also add `waitForExistence` to the dot to make sure the layout has fully loaded, then try and drag.

Comment: Unfortunately those tips didn't work for me.

Comment: What do you see if you do ‘po XCUIApplication()’?

Comment: What do you mean `po XCUIApplication()`? I have declared at the top of my XCTestCase class `let app = XCUIApplication()`. Are you referring to changing that in some way?

Comment: In the console, print the hierarchy of the app. You need to check that the elements you interact with are there. If you have an app variable already you can do ‘po app’. That should help you check if all the identifiers are there etc

Comment: Oh I see--you meant setting a breakpoint sometime after creating the XCUIApplication, running the test, and then entering `po app` in the debugger when it hit the breakpoint. I did that, and it looks like all the relevant elements are there.